# Run script tags loaded with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, cloudflare

### General Question

Say you have a simple ajax request like `$("#container").load('/url #content');`.  The loaded DOM will be something like

```
<a>email</a>
<script>/* some script */</script>
```

What can I do to get the contents of the script tags to execute?

### Specific Question

Cloudflare automatically protects email addresses in the DOM by replacing the text with `[email protected]` and including a script that unravels it.  However, the contents can be loaded asynchronously and the script that does the unraveling won't be executed.  I could just turn off the email protection feature (I think) but I'm wondering if there's another way around this.

### Example

See it in action at http://aysites.com/what -- click "Contact"

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't include the `<script>` on initial page load, and use `executeFunction();` in `$('#container').load('/url #content', function(){ // executeFunction(); }); `? -- *I'll leave the initial response, but I just read a comment below where the script is created dynamically by cloudflare, essentially rendering the method I mentioned unusable.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I'm not creating the script; it's being created automatically by Cloudflare and it depends on the email address it's obfuscating.

Comment: you see the <script> and all the functions inside of it being added to the dom, right? Also...see the italics in my response above^

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yes but it seems to be somewhat randomized (they also use the same `id` for multiple emails it seems, which is bad too).

Comment: I'll give an answer now, then.

Answer (score 3):

There is a pure js function which invokes the JavaScript compiler. It's `eval`. You need to use it.

**Examples:**

```
jQuery.globalEval("var newVar = true;")
```

[on jQuery.com](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.globalEval/)

**Or**

```
eval("x=10;y=20;document.write(x*y)");
document.write("<br />" + eval("2+2"));
document.write("<br />" + eval(x+17));
```

[on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp)

Answer (score 3):

My answer includes some of Tooraj's magic as well.

Basically, we're going to use the same load function, and in the callback, we're going to grab the script, take the functions from within it, then eval them.

```
$("#container").load('/url #content', function(){
  eval($('#container script').html()); 
});
```

using the above selector and grabbing the HTML out of that selector (which happens to be the functions in the script), we can then `eval` that function and have it run.

[Here's a working jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/zraJY/)

Comment: Why `eval` vs `$.globalEval`?  Why `.html` instead of `.text`?

Comment: @Explosion Pills `.text()` will not grab the script inside of the function for security purposes. `$.globalEval` is not something that I use. *It's not that I advise against it*, it's that I don't know it well enough to use in my responses, and that would be reckless of me.

Answer (score 1):

you could put the script part alone in a page with appropriate headers and then use `$.getScript()` to get and execute the script,

See Doc: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: The JavaScript is created automatically by cloudflare, so I don't put it anywhere.