# Return executable Javascript and html content with load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It's my understanding that eval() is more than likely the best option. But in my inserttest.php page it's a mixture of html and javascript. Only the javascript doesn't work when page load is completed and the content is put into the #light Div.

So my question is..Is the below the best method. And how would I go about editing it to allow all content to return as is.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form#myform").submit(function(event){
$('#light').load('inserttest.php');
});
});
</script>
```

I saw in this thread [[Run script tags loaded with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425718/run-script-][1]tags-loaded-with-ajax)

```
eval($('#container script').html());
```

I believe this would only return the script and no html/

UPDATE - Output of insertest.php

```
<form id="myformshareid"  method="POST"  class="form_statusinput">
<input type="hidden"  name="toid" id="toid" value="<? echo $user1_id ?>">
<input type="hidden"  name="streamitem_con" id="streamitem_con" value='<? echo $streamitem_data['streamitem_content'] ?>'/>
<input type="hidden"  name="streamitem_idsharetype" id="streamitem_idsharetype" value="<? echo $noterypes['streamitem_type_id'] ?>">
<input type="hidden"  name="streamitem_id" id="streamitem_id" value="<? echo $streamitem_data['streamitem_id'] ?>">
<div cols="40" rows="5" name="newmsg" id="newmsg" data-ph="Say something <? echo $data['first']; ?>..." contenteditable="true"></div>   
<select id="privacy" name="privacy">
<option value="1">Public</option>
<option value="2">Friends</option>
</select>
<select id="comments" name="comments">
<option value="1">Comments On</option>
<option value="2">Comments Off</option>
</select>
<input title="Share <? echo $data["fullname"] ?>'s ststus to your wall" style="cursor:pointer;color:#FFF;" type="submit" id="button" value="Share">
</form>

<div id="display"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('.pop').unbind().click(function() {
var streamitem_id = $(this).attr('id');
$.ajax({
type:"POST", 
url: "sharecollect.php",
data: { streamitem_id: streamitem_id, },  
success: function(data) {
$('.pop').css('overflow-y', 'auto'); 
$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');  
$("#sharecontent"+streamitem_id).html(data);
}
});
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can use `$.getScript()`... Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.

Comment: As stated in this thread? [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521108/dynamically-load-js-inside-js)

Comment: Depends on how the script is set up in `inserttest.php`. Important to understand that `document.ready` has already occured in the main page. `eval()` will not work on html

Comment: Someone has stated its buggy.

Comment: So refrain `document.ready` in the inserttest.php page too.

Comment: @sharptongue Then you cannot do that using JavaScript

Comment: No...the important point is if the script is before any elements, it will immediately fire before the elements it references exist because the document is already ready. We need more details on the generated output of that page

Comment: Added a tiny snippet of the page inserttest.php

Comment: script shown should work fine. Note you haven't prevented the default submit in main page

Comment: I've worked out what the issue finally were. I had forgot to add the class to the button so it wasn't firing. class='pop'. Something so simple. Thanks for your help guys..You made me look over ever single line of code with a very fine toothpick.

Answer (score -1):

If you really need to eval a script, don't use `eval` but something like this :

```
void function(global) {
  'use strict';

  var betterEval;

  betterEval = function(src, context) {
    return Function.call(null, 'global', '"use strict";' + src)(context || global);
  };

  // usage
  betterEval('console.log(global);');
}(this);
```

Comment: what does this have to do with running script inside jQuery load() ? eval what? Don't see how this answers the question at all

Comment: sharptongue asks how to run the embed script inside the response... then he can to this : `betterEval('var $ = global.$;' + $('#container script').text());` ;)

Comment: but the response is html and `load()` will execute script tags already

Comment: Hum,ok, sorry, I'm not familiar with jQuery... It's just a general notice about eval which should never be used